# How to display Image in flash for no copy image?

Tags: image, flash

How to display Image in flash for no copy image?

The image should be in flash variable and encrypt real image file name?

Have the project open source release?

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer to your question, but using flash for this just makes it annoying. The image can be still be saved by hitting the printscreen button.

Comment: There is **no way** to stop a user from saving an image you display to them.  They will point a camera at the everloving screen if they have to.

Comment: @monkey_boys: if you just want the user to not know the original file name, rename the file to something random.  If you are trying to stop hotlinking, that's a different problem.  Try checking HTTP_REFERRER or looking for a cookie set by your site.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what Firebug is? I have copied many images in original quality with it, even Zoomify ones in max resolution. You only can make the copy harder by encrypting everything.